# Why am I unable to extrude/translate along the Z-Axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I have a 2D mesh plane dividing into numerous faces. I have x amount of faces selected and I want to extrude or translate them along the z-axis to create a 3D model. I am trying to do this:

From the 5:30 mark to the 5:50 mark in this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbm9lPB5GPw#t=5m30s

My object will not move along the z-axis. The faces don't move at all, even if I type in the amount to move along the z-axis and press enter, it continues to just remain a 2D plane.

I can't figure out if I have a setting turned on or off that is causing this or if its something else. It seems it should be straightforward, but I have not been able to solve it.

**EDIT:**

[image]

I cannot get the selected faces to extrude/translate outward from the plane along the Z-Axis.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my .blend file

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29706

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or the .blend?

Comment: And you are pressing `E` `Esc` `G` `Z` `-4`?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I have tried E > Z > -4, E > Right Click > G > Z > -4, G > Z > -4 with no success. I posted the .blend file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the Z scale of the object is `0`.

Apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Scale*) or set the Z scale in *3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Transforms > Scale*:

[image]

Then extrude/translate should work fine.

Comment: Spot on, thank you. It makes perfect sense now for why it wasn't functioning the way I expected.

Comment: Could someone please explain why it's impossible to extrude along the Z-axis when scale is zero? If I need to extrude a flat plain then I set its Z-dimension to 0, but it automatically sets Z-scale to 0. But I need the object to be flat!

Comment: @user2513149 The scale multiplies the local position of all the vertices in the object; values > 1 move vertices farther from the object origin, values < 1 move them closer. 0 means all vertices will be *at* the object origin (on the axis in question). You could apply the scale (`Ctrl+A`) once you've flattened the object to reset the scale to 1, or leave the object scale at 1 and scale to 0 in edit mode do a one-time flattening without the need to apply.